# How update Room DB with API response if there is not data?

Tags: retrofit2, repository-pattern, rx-java2, android-room

I am trying to update my database (room) with the response of my call api if my database table is empty and return to my recyclerview

API

```
@GET("user/patient/")
Flowable<ResponsePatient> getPatients(@Header("Authorization") String userToken);
```

FactoryData.class

```
public Flowable<List<Patient>> getPatientFromApi(){
    String token = preferences.getValue(SDConstants.token);
    return apiNetwork.getPatients(token).map(new Function<ResponsePatient, List<Patient>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Patient> apply(ResponsePatient responsePatient) throws Exception {
            return PatientMapper.transform(responsePatient);
        }
    });
}


public Flowable<List<Patient>> listPatient(){

      return appDataBase.patientDao().listPatient()
            .switchIfEmpty(getPatientFromApi())
            .doOnNext(s -> appDataBase.patientDao().saveAll(s));

}
```

I not sure how to do this. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can solve my problem.

```
public Flowable<List<Patient>> getPatient(){
   return getPatientFromlocal()
            .take(1)
            .filter(list -> !list.isEmpty())
            .switchIfEmpty(
                    Flowable.defer(() -> getPatientFromApi()));
}

public Flowable<List<Patient>> getPatientFromlocal(){
    return appDataBase.patientDao().listPatient();
}

public Flowable<List<Patient>> getPatientFromApi(){
    String token = preferences.getValue(SDConstants.token);
    return apiNetwork.getPatients(token).map(new Function<ResponsePatient, List<Patient>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Patient> apply(ResponsePatient responsePatient) throws Exception {
            return PatientMapper.transform(responsePatient);
        }
    }).doOnNext(new Consumer<List<Patient>>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(List<Patient> patients) throws Exception {
            appDataBase.patientDao().saveAll(patients);
        }
    });
}
```